# Why does this script show all files in the directory and not just PDF files?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls, wildcards

I wrote the script below to find the number of PDF files in a given directory. However, it instead shows all the files in the directory:

```
#!bin/bash
message="."
message1="*.pdf"

ls -al $message $message1
```

What's wrong with the script?

Comment: Since you appear to be using `bash`, I'll refer you to [this method of counting the number of files in a directory](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004).  Any approach that uses `ls` is very likely to be non-portable and incorrect, so I'd advise against going down that road.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because this is what the `ls` command *should do*. Your script effectively runs

```
ls -al . *.pdf
```

And that *will* list all the files in current directory (as specified by **`.`**). Leave out the dot and you'll have just the PDFs.

Comment: It will also list the contents of any directory whose name ends in `.pdf` and it will not list hidden names.